# Android lifecycle observer

Tags: observer-pattern, android-livedata, android-workmanager

I've been learning about and using Android's new Jetpack feature **WorkManager**. 
The app basically sends images to the server in the background. It works well and the images are uploaded.

The problem is when I attempt to observe the work status so that I can stop the progress bar.
 Here's my observer

```
WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusById(catSyncRequest.getId())
            .observe(this, new Observer<WorkStatus>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkStatus workStatus) {
                    if (workStatus != null) {
                        //mTextView.append("SimpleWorkRequest: " + workStatus.getState().name() + "\n");
                    }

                    if (workStatus != null && workStatus.getState().isFinished()) {
                        //String message = workStatus.getOutputData().getString(MyWorker.EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE, "Default message");
                        //mTextView.append("SimpleWorkRequest (Data): " + message);
                    }
                }
            })
```

In the second line "**.observe**" cannot be resolved. As usual for any missing library it's highlighted red.

Here's a screenshot
[image]

I've checked online but nobody seems to be facing this problem. 
What could I be missing?

Comment: What version of WorkManager are you using? (your Gradle dependency). It seems to work just fine for me. Have you tried doing the old Android Studio `Invalidate caches / restart` [shuffle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html)?

Answer (score 2):

WorkManager 1.0 alpha 10 changed the return type of `getStatusById()` to a [`ListenableFuture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getstatusbyid).

If you want to use an observable you need to use the new API method: [`getStatusByIdLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getstatusbyidlivedata).